# Best practice error handling ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

Here is my scenario..
I want to handle code 403(unauthorized access) using specific view. All other exceptions using other views. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine)

Answer (score 0):

Using the try catch method.

```
try
    {
        //Perform some action here
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} First exception caught.", e);
    }
```

This is the simplest method to catch an exception.